# Extract values from inside JSON column in MySQL based on conditions

Tags: mysql, json, percona

Consider a table in MySQL 5.7.x having a JSON column.

```
-- CREATE TABLE "plans" -----------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `plans` ( 
  `id` VarChar( 36 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL,
  `name` VarChar( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `structure` JSON NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
  CONSTRAINT `index_exam_plans_on_id` UNIQUE( `id` ),
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The `structure` column has a JSON. Please find an example structure of the JSON below:

```
{
  "33aa1e1c-0c95-4860-9b71-ccd13f393dd0": {
    "name": "Term 1",
    "tags": [
      "Term"
    ],
    "type": "default",
    "uuid": "33aa1e1c-0c95-4860-9b71-ccd13f393dd0",
    "is_locked": false
  },
  "cb896a12-f07c-4bcc-9c22-7bdfa585f5f7": {
    "name": "English",
    "tags": [
      "Paper",
      "Course Paper"
    ],
    "type": "course_paper",
    "uuid": "cb896a12-f07c-4bcc-9c22-7bdfa585f5f7",
    "course_id": 1,
    "is_locked": false
  },
  "e6d2f9fb-0429-42b2-b704-c438e1695044": {
    "name": "Written Work",
    "tags": [
      "Paper",
      "Regular Paper"
    ],
    "type": "regular_paper",
    "uuid": "e6d2f9fb-0429-42b2-b704-c438e1695044",
    "course_id": 2,
    "is_locked": false
  },
  "d0d3eeff-9ffb-4f35-b0fb-b94373d1fe5b": {
    "name": "Summative Assessment",
    "tags": [
      "Exam"
    ],
    "type": "default",
    "uuid": "d0d3eeff-9ffb-4f35-b0fb-b94373d1fe5b",
    "is_locked": false
  },
  "0952e100-cd4a-473e-bd24-2370e0dfcc1c": {
    "name": "Speaking skills",
    "tags": [
      "Paper",
      "Regular Paper"
    ],
    "type": "regular_paper",
    "uuid": "0952e100-cd4a-473e-bd24-2370e0dfcc1c",
    "course_id": 5,
    "is_locked": false
  }
}
```

Points to note:

- The JSON is an object, containing any number of key-value pairs. The example structure has 5 key-value pairs.
- The "value" in each key-value pair is another JS object of key-value pairs. Let's call this the "inner JSON".
- Every inner JSON has a key called `type`.
- In the example structure above, the first and fourth inner JSONs have `default` as the value for the `type` key.

## The requirement

I want to find all the inner JSONs which have `type` set to `default`. This should be done in just SQL. For the example above, the output should be just the first and fourth inner JSONs.

How do I do this?

I have tried the following, but it does not return the inner JSONs based on the condition. It returns every inner JSON in the `structure` column.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(structure, '$.*') from plans 
where name = 'Academic' 
and JSON_CONTAINS( structure->'$.*.type', '"default"' );
```

Could somebody give the right way to go about this?

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499401](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499401).